# Refresh page with autoclicker

Tags: vb.net, browser, refresh

I have an autoclicker script that submits every so seconds (about 1 per second). When I tested it I noticed it could only run for about 20 minutes and then it would come unresponsive, and the only way I could think of fixing this is to have a script that refreshes the page every so seconds. However, when I tried this, It would not work because as it refreshes it would still try to autoclick and thus giving me a unresponsive error: http://gyazo.com/cfc3d673573d725042e3acc7142a53b9

The only way I can think to fixing this is to add a pause to the clicking button as it refreshes or a wait until document completed. It seemed like that would've worked great but I could never get it to work... :\ Any help? I've decided to post the source of my script if that helps: http://pastebin.com/4WMcn5Ln
I would post more but I can only post 2 links...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you get it working with the DocumentCompleted event:

```
Private Sub navBtnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim wbrowser = New WebBrowser()
    wbrowser.DocumentCompleted += New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted)
    wbrowser.Navigate("http://www.somesite.com/login")
End Sub

Public Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim webBrowser = TryCast(sender, WebBrowser)
    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted
    'MessageBox.Show(webBrowser.Url.ToString())
    webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("value", txtUsername.Text)
    webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("passwd").SetAttribute("value", txtPassword.Text)
    webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("SI").InvokeMember("Click")
End Sub
```

The DocumentCompleted event fires multiple times if the document being navigated to has iframes that embed other web pages. If you only want to receive the event exactly once, just unsubscribe from the DocumentCompleted handler as I've shown above.